# Multiton of Values from Func Delegates

Tags: c#

While there are answers that addresses Multitons via Lazy values in Concurrent Collections but this question involves Func Lambdas that receive and return value.

**Solution of Func only with a return type (accepts no params)**

```
public static IProduct GetInstance(string key, Func<IProduct> prod)
{
    return instances.GetOrAdd(key, new Lazy<IProduct>(prod)).Value;
}

// Usage

Product.GetInstance("foo", () => new Product("foo")); // without params
```

---

**Question** is for a Func that accepts a value and returns a value, so meaning there's some constructor call involved before it gets into a Lazy structure. How would such a problem be solved?

```
public static IProduct GetProductInstance(string key, Func<string, IProduct> prod) 
{

}


// Usage

Product.GetInstance("foo", key => new Product(key)); // with params
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking to achieve is passing the `key` into the constructor of `Product` then the following will do so:

```cs
public static IProduct GetProductInstance(string key, Func<string, IProduct> prod)
{
    return instanceMap.GetOrAdd(key, new Lazy<IProduct>(() => prod(key))).Value;
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit, so the `delegate` passed to the dictionary has to be parameterless, I was attempting `new Lazy<IProduct>( k => prod(k))`, meaning I'm expecting `Lazy` to pass the key to the delegate and get the value out of it

Comment: Since `Lazy<T>` doesn't know about the values needed to eventually construct whatever its constructing, it will only accept `Func<T>`. Which, as you've seen, means a lambda like `k => prod(k)` won't work (as it's of type `Func<T1, out TResult>`). With the power of closures however (as seen in my answer), the `key` and `prod` parameters are stored in a special class. That special class also has a method with signature `IProduct b__0()` (name of actual method might differ) which is perfectly assignable to `Func<T>`. And so it works. Does the code from my answer solve your problem though?